# Shortcuts not working when inspection panel open

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, vivaldi

I'm giving Vivaldi a shot as my primary browser and I've noticed a quirk that is bugging me.  When I inspect an html element (Ctrl+Shift+I) and make some css modifications, it seems that I cannot use the standard browser shortcuts (Ctrl+Tab, Ctrl+T, etc) until I click out of the inspection panel back into the webpage.  This isn't to say that all shortcuts are disabled, I can use inspection-specific shortcuts but no standard browser shortcuts.  Is there a shortcut to shift focus from the inspection pannel?

Comment: Do any of [these suggestions from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981973/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-focus-from-web-developer-tools-to-page-in-chrome) work? They're not specific to Vivaldi though. I take it you prefer to have the inspector docked? I always undock it, so I can just alt+tab between inspector and Vivaldi.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Good find from stack overflow but none of those worked.  You are right that I could undock it but I do prefer to keep the inspector docked to its corresponding window.  Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: No worries, good luck finding a solution. Vivaldi as main browser is worth it. ;-)

Comment: Apparently this is a known bug: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/76487/some-keyboard-shortcuts-stopped-working-i-developer-tools/8?_=1657036684369